# The Alexander-Conway polynomial: from knots to braids?

Tags: gr.group-theory, polynomials, braid-groups

The Alexander-Conway polynomial was the first knot invariant to be discovered, as far back as [1923](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_polynomial#Alexander.E2.80.93Conway_polynomial) according to this link. Given that knots can be expressed in terms of quasi-toric braid closures, it seems possible to extend this definition to arbitrary braids as follows. For a fixed integer $n$, we would ask for the existence of a polynomial $AC_n : B_n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[z]$ satisfying the relations:

> $AC_n(1) = 1$, where $1$ denotes the empty braid;
>   $AC_n(uv) = z ~ (AC_n(u \sigma_i v) - AC_n(u \sigma_i^{-1} v))$

for any $u,v \in B_n$ and any $i \in [n]$. This corresponds to the 'Conway skein relations' for knots, but it seems nontrivial to show that they lead to a well-defined object. Thus may I ask if you know about how to prove the existence/unicity of such an object? I expect that some people on this forum know about knot theory as it seems to be considered  a source of interesting problems in TCS.

Comment: This would be far better suited for MathOverflow.

Comment: This would be far better suited for MathOverflow. (Sorry for the duplicate comment - it forces me to add a comment when voting to close, which I did because this question should really be migrated to MO.)

Comment: Are you aware of the *Burau Representation*?  It is a very natural relative of the Alexander polynomial defined on braid groups.  It isn't exactly what you're asking for but perhaps it is closer to what you actually want?

Comment: This is not the question you want to ask. Closing up a braid to a knot should be thought of as a trace, so what you really want is a map from braids to matrices with polynomial coefficients (probably a representation of the braid group) such that taking traces gives back the Alexander polynomial (this is exactly what happens for the Jones polynomial, where the corresponding representation is built using e.g. quantum groups). Maybe the Burau representation is such a representation?